# Bigquery view getting error from python code

Tags: python, view, google-bigquery

We have created a **view on two tables within a dataset**. We are able to query the view from console Web UI. But when we try query the view from the Python client code using a service account key, we are getting an error - error code : **200, Bad Request, Invalid tablename**. We are able to query the underlying table using the same code. When we tried to replace the table name with view name, the code stops working.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


def test():
    client = bigquery.Client(project='project-name')
    query_results = client.run_sync_query("""
        SELECT column-names
        FROM `dataset.viewname`
        WHERE conditions
        ;""")

    query_results.use_legacy_sql = False
    query_results.run()
    page_token = None

    while True:
        rows, total_rows, page_token = query_results.fetch_data(
            max_results=1,
            page_token=page_token)

        for row in rows:
            print row
        if not page_token:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Also, when we set `query_results.use_legacy_sql = False`, we get below error:

`BadRequest: 400 Cannot reference a Legacy SQL view in a SQL query`

When we set `query_results.use_legacy_sql = True`, we get a different error:

`BadRequest: 400 Invalid table name: 'dataset.viewname'`

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping dataset.viewname with brackets instead of backticks if you are using legacy sql.

So, the query would be:

```
query_results = client.run_sync_query("""
SELECT column-names
FROM [dataset.viewname]
WHERE conditions
;""")
```

Documentation of the escaping differences between standard and legacy SQL:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#escaping_reserved_keywords_and_invalid_identifiers

We do suggest moving to standard SQL, though.

Comment: Thanks.. Moving to standard SQL and using #standard sql tag in view query helped to use standard query language. THe python code started working